# How to do a join with fields that are not keys nor have the same type in Access database?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access table called `CHECKINOUT` that has a field called `SENSORID` of text type.

On the other hand, there is another table called `Machines` that has a field called `MachineNumber` of int type.

`MachineNumber` is the join I need to do with `SENSORID` but it does not work.

This is the query I am trying:

```
SELECT C.VERIFYCODE, C.CHECKTYPE, C.CHECKTIME, C.sn, 
       U.USERID, U.BADGENUMBER, U.SSN, U.CardNo, U.NAME, U.STREET, U.PAGER, 
       C.SENSORID, M.IP, M.MachineAlias, M.Port,M.MachineNumber
FROM (CHECKINOUT C
      INNER JOIN USERINFO U ON C.USERID = U.USERID)
INNER JOIN Machines M ON C.SENSORID = Str(M.MachineNumber)
WHERE C.CHECKTIME >= #2022-11-01 12:00:00#
```

I got empty results.

I also tried with:

```
SELECT C.VERIFYCODE, C.CHECKTYPE, C.CHECKTIME, C.sn, 
       U.USERID, U.BADGENUMBER, U.SSN, U.CardNo, U.NAME, U.STREET, U.PAGER, 
       C.SENSORID, M.IP, M.MachineAlias, M.Port,M.MachineNumber
FROM (CHECKINOUT C
      INNER JOIN USERINFO U ON C.USERID = U.USERID)
INNER JOIN Machines M ON Val(C.SENSORID) = M.MachineNumber
WHERE C.CHECKTIME >= #2022-11-01 12:00:00#
```

but it did not work either.

Of course, there are matching data so result should not be empty.

[image]

[image]

What should I do to execute this query successfully?

Comment: Your syntax (both) seem correct, so try joining on the SensorId/MachineNr only.

Comment: I see 3 datasets in query so I don't think can remove the USERID join. Edit question to show sample raw data as text tables.

Comment: @Gustav I have added this to the field list: `(SELECT M2.MachineNumber FROM Machines M2 WHERE Str(M2.MachineNumber) = C.SENSORID)` and no match is returned, however, if I replace `C.SENSORID` by a hard coded `'4'`, it works. Furthermore, when I add `C.SENSORID = '4'` in the bottom `where` clause, the returned records are records whose `SENSORID` is equal to 4. I don't understand why the join does not work,

Comment: @June7 I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You don't understand request for sample data? Review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: @June7 i did not understant when you said: "I see 3 datasets in query so I don't think can remove the USERID join.".  However, I finally could solve the problem. I could use `INNER JOIN Machines M ON Val(C.SENSORID) = M.MachineNumber`. I don't know why it did not work the first time. What definetely does not work is using `Str` function.

Comment: You're aware that `Str` generates a string with a leading space for positive numbers? If you don't want a leading space you need `CStr`, `Str` is a weird function without a clear purpose.

Comment: @ErikA: Here, the leading space for positive numbers will not change the final SQL. Also, `Str` is in no way weird; it is the direct counterpart to `Val` and the only function useful for converting decimal numbers safely to string expressions in SQL, as it always return a dot as the decimal separator where `CStr` use the _local_ settings for the decimal separator. `LTrim` can be used to remove the leading space if necessary.